# Scala / Slick, "Timeout after 20000ms of waiting for a connection" error

Tags: mysql, scala, sbt, slick, hikaricp

The block of code below has been throwing an error.

```
  Timeout after 20000ms of waiting for a connection.","stackTrace":[{"file":"BaseHikariPool.java","line":228,"className":"com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool","method":"getConnection"
```

Also, my database accesses seem too slow, with each element of xs.map() taking about 1 second. Below, getFutureItem() calls db.run().

```
xs.map{ x => 
    val item: Future[List[Sometype], List(Tables.myRow)] = getFutureItem(x)         
    Await.valueAfter(item, 100.seconds) match {
        case Some(i) => i
        case None => println("Timeout getting items after 100 seconds")
    }
}
```

Slick logs this with each iteration of an "x" value:

```
[akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/24] Connection was PeerClosed, awaiting TcpConnection termination...
[akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/24] TcpConnection terminated, stopping
[akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
[akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/25] Dispatching POST request to http://localhost:8080/progress to handler Actor[akka://system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/26#-934408297]
```

My configuration:

```
"com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.3.2"

default_db {
  url = ...
  user = ...
  password = ...
  queueSize = -1
  numThreads = 16
  connectionPool = HikariCP
  connectionTimeout = 20000
  maxConnections = 40
}
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong that is causing these database accesses to be so slow and throw this error? I can provide more information if needed.

EDIT: I have received one recommendation that the issue could be a classloader error, and that I could resolve it by deploying the project as a single .jar, rather than running it with sbt.

EDIT2: After further inspection, it appears that many connections were being left open, which eventually led to no connections being available. This can likely be resolved by calling db.close() to close the connection at the appropriate time.

EDIT3: Solved. The connections made by slick exceeded the max connections allowed by my mysql config.

Comment: This is worth a read, but unlikely to be your root cause: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: Did you specify a driver? There should be a slick driver and a JDBC driver AFAIK.

Comment: Please add the resolution to the answer field and close it.

Answer (score 2):

OP wrote:

> EDIT2: After further inspection, it appears that many connections were being left open, which eventually led to no connections being available. This can likely be resolved by calling db.close() to close the connection at the appropriate time.
>
> EDIT3: Solved. The connections made by slick exceeded the max connections allowed by my mysql config.